# jquery to check for empty field

Tags: jquery

How can i use jquery to check for the empty input field / to check if the field contains a specified string?

I understand that valid8(); does something similar. Any working example?

Comment: @Pekka why in a comment? that's a good answer+1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.val()` will give you an input element's value.

```
if ($("#element").val() == "") alert ("Empty!");
```

alternatively, use the [jQuery form validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) which offers a broader range of possibilities (like enforcing a minimum length).

Comment: My only question here is, if i need to show the error message on screen without the use of the alert popup, how do i do that?

Comment: @user there are many ways to do that, e.g. jQuery UI's dialogs http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/